# Registering all changes (delete or select) inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, mutation-observers

I realize this question is highly specific but was hoping to get some help with my code. I want to track the contents of a droppable div, where some of the blocks have selects inside of them [`TTEST` and `CHG`] and blocks can also be deleted using a button.

[image]

[image]

I tried adding an event listener but you need to drag in a new block in order for the select to update and deleting a block doesn't trigger the change in `agg_output` either. Can someone help to make my `MutationObserver` do what I anticipate it to: **Whenever the user drags in a block, changes the block order, deletes a block, OR changes the selected dropdown, the `agg_output` should reflect that - and deleting a block only sometimes changes the `agg_output`**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#sortable_agg").sortable();
  $("#sortable_agg").disableSelection();
});

// remove the item from the list
$("#d_agg").on('click', '.delete', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});

// get the length every select in the droppable div
// create unique ids for each
function getNewId(type) {
  var newId;
  newId = $('#droppable').find('select').length
  return type + (newId + 1);
}

$(function() {
  $(".blocks").draggable();
  $('#droppable_blocks').droppable({
    accept: ".block",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var draggableId = ui.draggable.attr("id");
      var newid = getNewId(draggableId);

      $(this).append(`
        <div>
        <div>
        <div class="form-group drop_area">
        <label class="control-label" for="${newid}">${newid.replace(/[0-9]/g, '').toUpperCase()}</label>
        <button class="delete">Delete</button>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>`)
    }
  }).sortable({
    revert: false
  })
})


$(function() {
  $(".draggable_agg").draggable();
  $("#droppable_agg").droppable({
    accept: ".agg",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var draggableId = ui.draggable.attr("id");
      var newid = getNewId(draggableId);
      if (draggableId.includes("ttest")) {
        $(this).append(`<div class="form-group drop_area">
                        <label class="control-label" for="${newid}">T-TEST</label>
                        <select id="${newid}">
                        <option value="week1" selected>Week 1</option>
                        <option value="week2">Week 2</option>
                        <option value="week3">Week 3</option>
                        <option value="week4">Week 4</option></select>
                        <button class="delete">Delete</button>
                        </div>`)
      } else if (draggableId.includes("chg")) {
        $(this).append(`<div class="form-group drop_area">
                        <label class="control-label" for="${newid}">CHG</label>
                        <select id="${newid}">
                        <option value="week1" selected>Week 1</option>
                        <option value="week2">Week 2</option>
                        <option value="week3">Week 3</option>
                        <option value="week4">Week 4</option></select>
                        <button class="delete">Delete</button>
                        </div>`)
      } else {
        $(this).append(`
        <div>
        <div>
        <div class="form-group drop_area">
        <label class="control-label" for="${newid}">${newid.replace(/[0-9]/g, '').toUpperCase()}</label>
        <button class="delete">Delete</button>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>`)
      }
    }
  }).sortable({
    revert: false
  })
});


var target = document.querySelector('#droppable_agg')
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  var str = "";
  $('#droppable_agg label').each(function() {
    const txt = $(this).text()
    const val = $(this).parent().find("select").children("option:selected").val()
    str += "<tr><td>" + txt + (val ? ": " + val : "") + "</td></tr>";
  })
  let str_to_table = '<table>' + str + '</table>'
  document.getElementById("agg_output").innerHTML = str_to_table;
})

// configuration of the observer:
var config = {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  characterData: true
};
// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);

var selected_option = $('#RECIPE').children("option:selected").val()
console.log(selected_option)

$("#RECIPE").bind("change", function(event, ui) {
  var publisher = $("#RECIPE").val();
  if (publisher === "MEAN") {
    document.getElementById("droppable_agg").innerHTML = "";
    $("#droppable_agg").append($("<div><div><div class='form-group drop_area'><label class='control-label' for='mean_recipe'>MEAN</label><button class='delete'>Delete</button></div></div></div><div><div><div class='form-group drop_area'><label class='control-label' for='freq_recipe'>FREQ</label><button class='delete'>Delete</button></div></div></div>"));
  } else {
    document.getElementById("droppable_agg").innerHTML = "";
  }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 1000px;
  clear: both;
}

.left {
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.left-drop {
  width: 400px;
  float: left;
}

.right-drop {
  width: 400px;
  float: left;
}

.right {
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#agg_output {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: green;
}

#sortable_agg,
#sortable1,
#blocks,
#block {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.droppable_blocks li {
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

#sortable_agg li,
#blocks li,
#block li,
.droppable_blocks li {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

#sortable_agg:hover,
#blocks li:hover {
  cursor: grab;
}

#sortable_agg .ui-sortable-helper:hover,
#blocks .ui-sortable-helper:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-color: black;
}

#sortable_agg .ui-sortable-helper:hover,
#blocks .ui-sortable-helper:hover {
  cursor: grabbing;
}

.droppable_agg {
  border: 2px dashed #466683;
  padding: 1em;
  min-height: 200px;
}

#droppable_agg.ui-droppable-hover {
  background: #bad4ed;
}

#droppable_blocks.ui-droppable-hover {
  background: #bad4ed;
}

#droppable_agg select {
  margin: 5px;
}

.drop_area {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
}

.delete {
  background: none;
  border: 0px;
  color: #888;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 60px;
  margin: 0px 0 0;
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}

button:hover {
  color: #CF2323;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<select id="RECIPE">
  <option id="none">NONE</option>
  <option id="mean">MEAN</option>
</select>

<div class="wrapper">
 
  <div class="right-drop" id="d_agg">
    Drop Here
    <ul id="droppable_agg" class="ui-sortable-helper sortTxtbox droppable_agg">
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    Stats
    <br>
    <br>
    <ul id="sortable_agg">
      <li class="ui-state-default agg" id="ttest">T-Test</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default agg" id="chg">CHG</li>
      <li class="agg" id="mean">Mean</li>
      <li class="agg" id="freq">Freq</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div id="agg_output"></div>
</div>
```

Again thanks for any help - if useful code is also here

(https://codepen.io/mayagans/pen/RwNeezw)

Comment: 1) Switching a value in `<select>` doesn't change DOM so it won't be reported in MutationObserver, you should use a `change` or `input` event listener. 2) To detect a deleted element you can analyze the parameter `mutations`, look for examples of using its `removedNodes` property.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I'm still struggling to apply this to my example - do you have any more guidance on how I would implement this given that there could be multiple selects within the `droppable_agg` div and I'm trying to track multiple changes at once? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Add the event listener on the container and use `e.target` to identify the source of change assuming `e` is the listener's parameter.